# How to Retrieve Dynamic Link from Economic-Times using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

The parse_new_items function doesn't retrieve the link, I think the link is being generated dynamically hence the problem. I have looked at other posts but I am not able to solve this problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class EtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'et'
    start_urls = ["https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive.cms"]

    def parse(self, response):
        months = response.xpath('//table//tr//a/@href').re(r'/archive/year-\d+,month-\d+.cms')
        for month in months:
            month = 'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com' + month  
            yield scrapy.Request(month, self.parse_news_item)
            
    def parse_news_item(self, response):
        days = response.xpath('//table//tr//td//tbody//tr//td//a/@href').re(r'/archivelist/year-\d+,month-\d+,starttime-\d+.cms')
        for day in days:
            self.logger.info(day)
        
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(EtSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html